# How to resolve this error "undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromObject " while including Python packages in Odoo 8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, ucs2, ucs

I downloaded *pyodbc* python package and tried using it for *Odoo 8*, but I am getting the following error:

> undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromObject

The system python has *UCS4* support, but the Odoo python has *UCS2* support, Anyone with any idea on this would really helpful. Thanks !!!